# Variable number of arguments to a single function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried some code but I am not getting a satisfactory answer. The output of the code should be the exact number arguments from the call site:

```
>>> def  Hello(PitU,*V):
    print("you passed" , PitU,"Arguments")
    for Pit in V:
        print(Pit)

#case1      
>>> Hello(3,"one","two","three")
you passed 3 Arguments
one
two
three

#case2
>>> Hello(3,"one","two")
you passed 3 Arguments
one
two

#case3
>>> Hello(3,"one","two","three","four")
you passed 3 Arguments
one
two
three
four
>>>
```

I expect the output to be:

```
A. case-1
you passed 3 Arguments
one
two
three

B. case-2
error

C. case-3
error

instead of 

Case1
you passed 3 Arguments
one
two
three

case2
you passed 3 Arguments
one
two

case3
you passed 3 Arguments
one
two
three
four
```

Comment: For future reference, after pasting code into a question (or answer), select the code and either type Ctrl+K or click the `{}` button in the editor interface to format the code properly. I've fixed the main block of it for you here.

Comment: Why do you think the value of the first argument is in anyway related to the `*` parameter?

Comment: Unless you need to specify how many arguments should follow, you could omit the parameter. Then if you want to print how many there were, just change your code to `print("you passed" , len(V),"Arguments")`

Answer (score 3):

For that you need to put a check yourself, python won't do that for you.

```py
def Hello(PitU, *V): 
    if len(V) != PitU:
        print("error")
        return
    print("you passed", PitU, "Arguments") 
    for Pit in V: 
        print(Pit)
```

Answer (score 3):

Because PITu isn't the number of the arguments you must pass, it's just another argument you put there. there is nothing wrong with python technique, you just misunderstood its concept.